# Horizontal slides with vertically scrollable content inside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, iscroll, swiper.js

basically what i want to do is to slide between divs (slides) with vertically scrollable content in my JQuery Mobil app.

currently i have done it using a combination of [owl carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) and [iscroll5](http://iscrolljs.com). Unfortunately owl carousel currently doesn't support infinite scrolling - it won't slide back to the first slide from the last.

Hence again i'm trying to achieve this using combinations of various carousel plugins like [excolo](http://excolo.github.io/Excolo-Slider/) carousel with iscroll, [swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/index.php) with iscroll etc for creating a horizontal carousel in which each slide will have vertically scrollable content.

but i'm having trouble making these plugins work together. excolo and iscroll5 works fine except when the number of slides is exactly 3.
swiper and iscroll is also having issues since iscroll is not applied to the   duplicate elements created dynamically by swiper.

Recently i found that swiper has a scrollbar plugin, however it scrolls horizontally with horizontal slider and verivally with a vertical slider, but i need the opposite behavior. i'm trying to achieve this by nesting a vertical slider inside a horizontal slider with iDangerous swiper..

has anybody else done anything like this?

forget the plugins, any way to achieve this?

(please don't ask what have you tried, the code i've written with all this combinations can't be put inside a single question, i'll try to put what i'm doing with the swiper and it's scollbar plugin though..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iDangero.us here:) You can use Swipe for your horizontal slider, but if you do a mobile app, you probably don't need at all another nested scrollable plugin/script inside. I did it a lot of times and old school overflow:auto feet for this very well, why you don't use it? ;)